# Make 'Related To' section based on same Category in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a website where i post recipes. each one of them has a category, and i want to display 2-3 more posts with the same category of that post.
how can i build a query to display it? i have a Post Model and Category model that has a belongsToMany relation between the two, and it fills a pivot table, that i bind those categories to a post.

This is the function in my BController, this is the function that passes data to the views where users can access and view.

```
public function slug(Request $request, $slug)

    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
          $fav = DB::table('post_user')->whereUserId(Auth::id())->pluck('post_id')->all();
        }
         /*get search query from slug page*/
        $query=$request->get('q');
        /*display the results of the search*/
        if ($query) {
            $posts = $query ? Post::search($query)
            ->orderBy('id','desc')
            ->paginate(7) : Post::all();
            return view('home', compact('posts','fav'));
        }
       /*the $url veriable is for share buttons*/
           else {
            $url = $request->url();
            $post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
            return view('b.s', compact('post','url'));

        }
    }
```

**this is my Post model:**

```
    public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}
```

**this is in Category model:**

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
}
```

**The pivot table is like so:**

```
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')
            ->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')
            ->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `whereHas` to add constraints on related table as:

```
// get the post usnig slug
$post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

// get the related categories id of the $post
$related_category_ids = $post->categories()->pluck('categories.id');

// get the related post of the categories $related_category_ids
$related_posts = Post::whereHas('categories', function ($q) use($related_category_ids) {
        $q->whereIn('category_id', $related_category_ids)
    })
    ->where('id', '<>', $post->id)
    ->take(3)
    ->get();
```

**Update**

Pass the `$related_posts` to your view and use it as:

```
@foreach ($related_posts as $related_post)
    <li>{{ related_post->title }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Your code got me this: `Collection {#247 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => "12"
  ]
}` how can i access the actual posts with this? Im sorry for being a noob here, but i am. started this couple od days ago, and still learning ofcourse. Thank you.

Comment: At which line you are getting this?

Comment: I get it when i do `dd($related_category_ids);`

Comment: That's correct. Try the next query and you will get the related posts.

Comment: I do get a collection of 5 posts, how can i access each item in that collection using this variable?

Comment: what i mean is, how can i use that collection to actually show the posts?

Comment: Pass it to your view and use it in blade's foreach as https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#loops

Comment: What i mean is, how to access each post within that variable, lets say the posts title. how can i access it? like so,` $related_posts->title`?

Comment: Thank you very much. it works great. by the way, how can i limit it to get only 3 related posts?

Comment: You can use `take(3)` method. Check the updated answer.

Comment: That is awesome. i also tries to take 3 random posts with the `random()` method, but it did not work. but hi, you helped me so much. it is very much appreciated!

Comment: Glad I could help you. You can ask a different question for that, we may help in that also.

Answer (score 1):

On possible solution is to include a piece of code to get the required categories.

If I correctly understand your model, you can have several categories. So, we need to take all Categories of your post, and keep only the id ; and we have to exclude the Post ID of the current object :)

```
$post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

// get Category IDs. There are others ways to do it.
$categoriesId = [];
foreach( $post->categories as $category ) {
  $categoriesId[] = $cateogyr->id;
}

// get similar posts
$others = Post::
     whereIn('categories', $categoriesId)
   ->where('id', '!=', $post->id)
   ->take(3)
   ->get();
```

In your case, you have a pivot table:

```
$others = Post::
   with(array('YourPivot' => function($query) use($categoriesId)
     {
       whereIn('categories', $categoriesId)
     })
   ->where('id', '!=', $post->id)
   ->take(3)
   ->get();
```

Comment: Can you explain the french?

Comment: Oh sorry. I don't know why I wrote in french. I will translate ^^

Comment: Thanks, but i get this error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::andWhere()`

Comment: Remove the "and', and use instead `where`.

Comment: Now i get this error, because i don't have a "categories" filed in my posts table, its in a pivot table like i said in the OP. `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from posts where categories in (10) and id != 33 limit 3)`. What can i do?

Comment: Here this is a list of all IDs. What is the field linked to categories ? `category_id`, no ? Try with it.

Comment: This will go to the pivot table?

Comment: Nothing like that is working, because there is no `category_id` or `categories` colum in my posts table. the categories and posts are binded with the pivot table, and that what i need to know, how to reference other categories with the same category on the pivot table, and get 3 posts with that category.

Comment: Yes, I see it. You need to load the missing field with `with` instruction. See my edited post :)

Comment: Hi, what you wrote is not possible, i cant do `$others = Post::
   ->with` did you meant `$others = Post::with`, i cant to that too. Please see if what you wrote is correct, because errors are shown.

Comment: Im sorry for being a noob here, i have started laravel only a few days ago.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. `::->` is not possible :) But good job, you see it !